# CSS of the admin panel

Tags: wp-admin, css

Where can i get hold of the CSS of the admin panels? Id like to make it look different on my development environment so that no one changes the production server by mistake. Like giving it a different background-color.

Comment: you can use Blue Admin  plugin for this and many more for the dashbord customisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to enqueue a style.css for the admin panel.

Create a file to say `custom-css.css` and add css to it and then enqueue it to the admin by putting the below in the theme's `function.php` file.

```
function admin_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css', content_url() . '/themes/theme-name/custom.css');
    //Please replace the path with the correct path to the file in your theme 
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_enqueue' );
```